# NOT IN vs IN Do Not Return Complimentary Results

Tags: sql

Hi I am working through example #7 from the sql zoo tutorial: [SELECT within SELECT](http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/SELECT_within_SELECT_Tutorial). In the following question

"Find each country that belongs to a continent where all populations are less than 25000000. Show name, continent and population."

I get the right answer by using NOT IN and a sub query like this:

```
SELECT name, continent, population FROM world 
WHERE continent NOT IN (
    SELECT continent FROM world
    WHERE population > 25000000)
```

If I on the other hand use "IN" instead of "NOT IN" and "population < 25000000" I do not get the right answer and I can not understand why that is, there is probably simple reason for this I just don't see it, can anyone explain it to me?

Comment: Have you examined the results of the individual sub-queries?

Comment: "population < 25000000" and "population > 25000000" do not cover all cases.

Comment: Probably because, other than antarctica, there are no continents which have a population smaller than 25,000,000, so you're trying to do `... where in (null)`.

Comment: You should be using `NOT EXISTS`

Comment: why using subqueries here ???

Comment: You should be summing all the populations by continent in the subquery, shouldn't you? (Not that a subquery is necessarily the best approach here.)

Comment: I don't think this is the problem, but technically the opposite of population > 25000000 is population <= 25000000

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO shouldn't (in SQL set theory) this be equivalent conditions, thus optimizer can replace the condition into IN or EXISTS or flat query before exeution - just anyway it would like ?

Comment: @MarcB - Why not? Does not mention the population of what!

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly, the question asks to list every country in a continent where every country has a population below 25000000, correct? If yes, look at your sub query. You are pulling every continent that has a country w/ population over 25000000, so excluding those is why it works. If you go the other way, if ANY country is below 25000000, it will display the continent, but you only want it if every country is below.

Comment: I think such a question should b e reported with table definition, including indices, and the exact version and vendor of SQL server. Afterall different engines have very different access methods and thus their optimizers have very different limitations in re-wording the query.

Comment: @Arioch'The [See this article](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join)

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO thanks. I was making my tests about NULL, and did not thought about EXISTS working with NULLs differently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm reading this correctly, the question asks to list every country in a continent where every country has a population below 25000000, correct?

If yes, look at your sub query:

```
SELECT continent FROM world
WHERE population > 25000000
```

You are pulling every continent that has at least one country w/ population over 25000000, so excluding those is why it works.

Example: Continent Alpha has 5 countries, four of them are small, but one of them, country Charlie has a population of 50000000.

So your sub query will return Continent Alpha because country Charlie fit the constraint of population > 25000000. This sub query will find everything that you don't want, that's why using the not in will work.

On the other hand:

```
SELECT continent FROM world
WHERE population > 25000000
```

If ANY country is below 25000000, it will display the continent, which is not what you want, because you want EVERY country to be below.

Example: Continent Alpha from before, the four small countries. Those four are below 25000000, so they will be returned by your sub query, regardless of the fact that Country Charlie has 50000000.

Obviously, this is not the best way to go about it, but this is why the first query worked, and the second did not.

Comment: So you are saying that by using "IN" I get every continent with at least one country with less that 25000000 in population, this is probably right, thanks.

Comment: Yes, that's correct, because that's what the sub query is doing. Sorry it wasn't the best wording. I've edited it to clear it up a little bit.

Comment: @Julian would it be possible to also point out which way is the best way to go about solving the problem in your understanding? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Because every other continent has at least one country with less then 25 Mio population. That is what this says.

```
  SELECT name, continent, population FROM world 
WHERE continent IN (
    SELECT continent FROM world
    WHERE population < 25000000)
```

Translating it into words: From the list of all countries (in table world) please find all countries where the continent has a country that has less than 25 Mio population.

Answer (score 0):

why use a sub query?

try using:

```
SELECT name, continent, population FROM world 
WHERE population > 25000000
```

and/or

```
SELECT name, continent, population FROM world 
WHERE population <= 25000000
```

the column of your condition: "population" is in the `FROM` table: "world".  There is no need to use a sub query of the same table "world" again, just use the "population" column directly in the `WHERE`

or are you trying to do this:

```
SELECT name, continent, population FROM world 
WHERE continent NOT IN (
    SELECT continent FROM world
    GROUP BY continent 
    HAVING SUM(population) > 25000000)
```

notice the: SUM(), GROUP BY, and HAVING

Answer (score 0):

Show the table DECLARATION. It seems you use CONTINENT as the continent number. Then you should check it is marked with PRIMARY KEY and NOT NULL options.
I realyl suspect you just forgot about very special meaning NULL has in SQL.

I make an example in Firebird 2.5.1 SQL server.

```
CREATE TABLE WORLD (
    CONTINENT   INTEGER,
    NAME        VARCHAR(20),
    POPULATION  INTEGER
);


INSERT INTO WORLD (CONTINENT, NAME, POPULATION) VALUES (NULL, 'null-id', 100);
INSERT INTO WORLD (CONTINENT, NAME, POPULATION) VALUES (1, 'normal 1', 10);
INSERT INTO WORLD (CONTINENT, NAME, POPULATION) VALUES (2, 'normal 2', 200);
INSERT INTO WORLD (CONTINENT, NAME, POPULATION) VALUES (3, 'null-pop', NULL);
INSERT INTO WORLD (CONTINENT, NAME, POPULATION) VALUES (4, 'normal 4', 110);

COMMIT WORK;
```

Now let's try your requests and see if the 1st row, having CONTINENT IS NULL would be present anywhere:

```
SELECT continent, population FROM world
WHERE continent IN (
    SELECT continent FROM world
    WHERE population > 100)

CONTINENT   POPULATION
2           200
4           110
```

and then

```
SELECT continent, population FROM world
WHERE continent NOT IN (
    SELECT continent FROM world
    WHERE population > 100)

CONTINENT   POPULATION
1           10
3           <NULL>
```

By the logic of the request you suppose CONTINENT to be the row ID, then you should make it NOT-NULL and then there would not be the line, that is not seen by [NOT] IN condition.

---

Now, let re-phrase this into flat query:

```
SELECT continent, population FROM world
    WHERE NOT (population > 100)

CONTINENT   POPULATION
<NULL>      100
1           10

SELECT continent, population FROM world
    WHERE population > 100

CONTINENT   POPULATION
2           200
4           110
```

This time the missed row was the one having NULL for Population column.

---

Then **FreshPrinceOfSO** suggested using EXISTS clause. While potentially it may end with most slow (non-effective) query plan, it at least masks away the special meaning of NULL value in SQL.

```
SELECT continent, population FROM world w_ext
WHERE EXISTS (
   SELECT continent FROM world w_int
   WHERE (w_int.population > 100) and (w_int.continent = w_ext.continent)
)

CONTINENT   POPULATION
2   200
4   110

SELECT continent, population FROM world w_ext
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT continent FROM world w_int
   WHERE (w_int.population > 100) and (w_int.continent = w_ext.continent)
)

CONTINENT   POPULATION
<NULL>  100
1   10
3   <NULL>
```