# having clause without aggregate in select

Tags: sql

Similar to this question: [NOT IN vs IN Do Not Return Complimentary Results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16551311/not-in-vs-in-do-not-return-complimentary-results)

Basically I am trying to answer this question: Find each country that belongs to a continent where all populations are less than 25000000. Show name, continent and population.

Number 7 here has all the table details: http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/SELECT_within_SELECT_Tutorial

This query works: it effectively takes all countries belonging to a continent which has no country with a pop greater than 25mm

```
SELECT name, continent, population 
FROM world x  
WHERE continent NOT IN(SELECT DISTINCT continent FROM world
WHERE population >= 25000000)
```

This query does not work. I am trying to use having without having an aggregate function in the select statement. Is this allowed? Currently my subquery returns no results, so I am obviously mistaken somewhere.

```
SELECT name, continent, population 
FROM world x  
WHERE continent in (SELECT  continent FROM world
having max(population) < 25000000)
```

Comment: Please provide a few example rows from the WORLD table or at least a list of all the columns.

Comment: You don't get a result because MySQL allows the `MAX()` aggregate without `GROUP BY`. You'll need to apply a group for the `MAX(population)` to make sense. (this would be an error in most other RDBMS)

Comment: "Find each country that belongs to a continent where all populations are less than 25000000" Does this mean a continent that collectively -- among all member countries -- is less than that amount? OR where all member countries' populations are individually less than that amount?

Comment: You're probably looking for `continent in (SELECT  continent FROM world GROUP BY continent having max(population) < 25000000)`

Comment: Each individually less than that amount, Brian.

Comment: what if you don't want to show the population field in your query output and still wanna use 'HAVING max(population) < 25000000)' ? And you also can't use GROUP BY clause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out, thank you @Michael Berkowsiki for the hint in the comment above.

```
SELECT name, continent, population 
FROM world x  
WHERE continent in (SELECT  continent FROM world
group by continent
having max(population) < 25000000)
```

Comment: what if you don't want to show the population field in your query output and still wanna use 'HAVING max(population) < 25000000)' ?

Answer (score 0):

"Each column referenced in the SELECT statement must be referenced in the GROUP BY clause, unless the column is an argument for an aggregate function included in the SELECT clause." ("Modern Database Management" 10th Edition, Jefferey A. Hoffer, Page 276)

So in this case, I believe your answer needs to be modified as:

```
SELECT name, continent, population 
FROM world x  
WHERE continent in (SELECT  continent FROM world
                    group by name, continent, population
                    having max(population) < 25000000)
```